# When speaking to (or rather writing about) a Sci Fi/Fantasy World what is a "PERSON"

Tags: aliens, terminology, sentience

Whether it is the original author or fan's engaged in discussion, Does the word "Person" exclusively refer to a "human" or can non-humans be "persons" too?

Are Elves "People", was (is) Yoda a person?

Comment: I've answered this here, but I think you might be better off at writers.stackexchange.com, if you are looking for authors' perspectives.

Comment: Technically, this is a question about [english.se], but since it's about usage amongst the kind of people who would frequent [scifi.se], I guess this is a good place for it.

Comment: @Jeff and @Gilles, I am _neither_ looking for an _author's_  perspective nor am I really concerned with the _proper_ English usage. I would guess that since neither Elves nor Wookies are _real_ I am guessing that English language scholars (excluding J.R.R. Tolkien) have put much thought into this subject. Rather what I am interested in is, "What does the audience **Think** when they hear the word "person" in a sci-fi/fantasy context. Perception is reality, at least for the reader :)

Comment: Isn't this a bit too subjective? The definition could easily vary from author to author.

Comment: If it weren't "subjective" I would just look it up. As I said I am looking to see what the audience thinks about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word “person” usually includes any entity that is sufficiently human-like in terms of social behavior. If it has a will or mind of its own, then it's a person. This extended usage predates science-fiction; in legal terminology, the word “person” includes any entity that can be a party to a contract, including corporations.

When discussing science-fiction, “person” generally includes any entity that's thought of as a character. That can include aliens, fantasy beings, artificial intelligences, … In-story, there can be a debate as to whether a particular entity or class of entity is considered a person for this or that purpose.

Related tropes (non-exclusive list):

- [What measure is a non-human?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhatMeasureIsANonHuman)
- [Not even human](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NotEvenHuman)
- [Android are people too](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AndroidsArePeopleToo)
- [Just a machine](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/JustAMachine)
- [Sliding scale of robot intelligence](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SlidingScaleOfRobotIntelligence)
- [Clones are people too](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ClonesArePeopleToo)
- [Zombie advocate](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ZombieAdvocate)

Comment: Even if I didn't agree fully, I'd have to give a +1 for the TV tropes links...y'know, now that I finished reading them.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the POV character, frankly.  A 'person' is defined by the entity applying labels.  So, while most sci-fi protagonists will grant the 'person' status to any sentient, other characters (more bigoted) may not see aliens as 'people', but as 'things'.

The same can apply to androids, AIs, and other non-carbon based sentients.